# MySQL LEFT JOIN Select all from one table then all matching records from another

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am trying to select all of the records from my articles table that match several possible variables. This has always worked as expected but now, for each result, I want to select the record from my images table where the image id matches the article id.

```
public static function getList( $headingId=null, $groupId=null, $subId=null, $query=null ) {
$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
$headingClause = $headingId ? "WHERE articles.headingId = :headingId" : "";
$groupClause = $groupId ? "AND articles.groupId = :groupId OR articles.group2Id = :groupId OR articles.group3Id = :groupId" : "";
$subClause = $subId ? "AND articles.subId = :subId OR articles.sub2Id = :subId OR articles.sub3Id = :subId" : "";
$searchClause = $query ? "AND articles.title LIKE '%" . $query . "%' OR articles.summary LIKE '%" . $query  ."%' OR articles.content LIKE '%" . $query  ."%'" : "";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles LEFT JOIN images ON articles.imageId = images.id $headingClause $groupClause $subClause $searchClause";

$st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
if ( $headingId ) $st->bindValue( ":headingId", $headingId, PDO::PARAM_INT );
if ( $groupId ) $st->bindValue( ":groupId", $groupId, PDO::PARAM_INT );
if ( $subId ) $st->bindValue( ":subId", $subId, PDO::PARAM_INT );
$st->execute();
$list = array();

while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
  $article = new Article( $row );
  $list[] = $article;
}

$conn = null;
return ( array ( "results" => $list ) );
```

}

I don't get any results from this. What else can I try?

Update: I've figured out that duplicated column names in the tables were conflicting. This query is giving me results but all but the first image is displayed with an error.

```
$headingClause = $headingId ? "AND articles.headingId = :headingId" : "";
$groupClause = $groupId ? "AND articles.groupId = :groupId OR articles.group2Id = :groupId OR articles.group3Id = :groupId" : "";
$subClause = $subId ? "AND articles.subId = :subId OR articles.sub2Id = :subId OR articles.sub3Id = :subId" : "";
$searchClause = $query ? "AND articles.title LIKE '%" . $query . "%' OR articles.summary LIKE '%" . $query  ."%' OR articles.content LIKE '%" . $query  ."%'" : "";
$sql = "SELECT articles.*, images.file FROM articles LEFT OUTER JOIN images ON articles.imageId = images.id $headingClause $groupClause $subClause $searchClause";
```

I only need one field from the images table and I don't need the other fields to match the query variables.

Comment: Could you add your Database Schemas and possibly the resulting SQL in that $sql-Variable?

Comment: Can you how your query without php code?

Comment: Can we see the actual query

Comment: I'm really sorry but I'm very new to all of this so I'm not sure how to do any of that.